# How deal with difference in English spelling from different countries in nltk tagger in python

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

I am using python 2.7 nltk tagger to tag a simple english text in order to  extract the frequency of each word and its named entity category. The following program is used for the purpose:

```
 import re
 from collections import Counter
 from nltk.tag.stanford import NERTagger
 from nltk.corpus import stopwords

 stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))

WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')

def main ():
    text = "title Optimal Play against Best Defence: Complexity and   
    Heuristics"
    print text
    words = WORD.findall(text)
    print words
    word_frqc = Counter(words)

    tagger = ERTagger("./classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz",  
    "stanford-ner.jar")
    terms = []
    answer = tagger.tag(words)
    print answer
    for i, word_pos in enumerate(answer):
        word, pos = word_pos
        if pos == 'PERSON':
           cat_Id = 1
        elif pos == 'ORGANIZATION':
           cat_Id = 2
        elif pos == 'LOCATION':
           cat_Id = 3
        else:
            cat_Id = 4
        frqc =word_frqc.get(word)
        terms.append( (i, word, cat_Id, frqc ))
print terms
if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

The output of the program is as follows:

```
text = "title Optimal Play against Best **Defence:** Complexity and    
    Heuristics"

[(u'title', u'O'), (u'Optimal', u'O'), (u'Play', u'O'), (u'against', u'O'),       
 (u'Best', u'O'), (u'Defense', u'O'), (u'Complexity', u'O'), (u'and', u'O'),  
 (u'Heuristics', u'O')]

 [(0, u'title', 4, 1), (1, u'Optimal', 4, 1), (2, u'Play', 4, 1), (3, 
   u'against', 4, 1), (4, u'Best', 4, 1), (5, u'**Defense**', 4, None), (6, 
   u'Complexity', 4, 1), (7, u'and', 4, 1), (8, u'Heuristics', 4, 1)]
```

There is one problem and is caused by the tagger.tag() method. The method change the  word 'defence'  in original text to 'defense'. Consequently the program cannot see the word 'defense' in word_frqc and therefore sets the frequency of the word in the text  to  None.

Please is there a way (in python) I can make the method not to change word?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.

Try to install geography with

> pip install geography.

check the [github repo here](https://github.com/ushahidi/geograpy)